# With robotframework, is it possible to do something after the test was over?

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to send the test report of Robot Framework by email for example to the leader.
Recently, I made a send email library to use in robotframework's Suite Teardown, but soon, I found that the test report was generated after executing the Suite Teardown, so can not obtain the report.
I wonder is there a way to do something like that in robotframework after the suite is over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make your mentioned library a Robot Framework library listener as described here: http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-libraries-as-listeners

As at the time the `close` listeners method is called, the context with automatic variable `${REPORT_FILE}` is gone, you need to combine it e.g. with library constructor like this:

```
class YourLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self._path_to_report = BuiltIn().get_variable_value('${REPORT_FILE}')

    def _close(self):
        self.call_your_method_to_send_the_report(self._path_to_report)
```

Note: it shouldn't matter if you'll use listener version 2 or 3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,i would try it!

Comment: Dear Jan,i have try that,but the report was generated after executing _CLOSE() method.

Comment: That sounds pretty strange to me. I've tried to copy the file to another path (by `copy file` from OperatingSystem lib) and it worked.

Comment: I solve it! Making a thread in _CLOSE() method,call the sending email method in the thread,for working normally,add a sleep in the thread.And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Although @Jan is correct that using the `close event` of the listener will allow you to do this, the real question is if you should. In my mind this no longer has anything to do with Test Automation and more with orchestration. Functionality like this typically expands over time and then this will certainly be the wrong place to put it.

This is why I would recommend looking at Jenkins (or any other CI like TravisCI, Bamboo etc) which has this kind of emailing functionality out-of-the-box. It will be a better maintainable solution over time and more flexible for future functionality.

For Robot Framework there exists a specific [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin).

Comment: I can only say that I more than agree. Thanks @AKootstra

Comment: Thanks! my company dose not have CI system yet,but i will keep your suggestion in my mind.

Comment: The key thing is that you keep the two functionalities separate. For example by having two python or command line scripts that are started separately from a single orchestration script. This will allow you to have a simple solution today, but less of a headache when you want to move towards an (open source) CI system like Jenkins.